# How do I make a Javascript POST request with the KuCoin API?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, kucoin

I'm trying to build a JavaScript/jQuery script which uses the KuCoin API. I'm specifically trying to use the KuCoin API from the browser console, not from Node JS or a local file.

I have some success with the KuCoin API and I can make signed REST GET requests but I cannot get my REST POST requests to work. Here is my code:

```
// VARIABLES
var burl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.kucoin.com'
var api_key = "xxx"
var api_secret = "xxx"
var api_passphrase = "xxx"
var endPointAccount = '/api/v1/accounts';
var endPointOrder = '/api/v1/orders';

// REST (Account)
// This signed GET request works
var now = Date.now();
var hey = now + "GET" + endPointAccount

/* signature */
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(hey, api_secret);
var signatureInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);

/* passphrase */
var passphrase = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(api_passphrase, api_secret);
var passphraseInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(passphrase);

var headers = {
    "KC-API-SIGN": signatureInBase64,
    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": now,
    "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphraseInBase64,
    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2"
}

var url = burl + endPointAccount;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: headers,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});


// REST (Order Limit BUY)
var now = Date.now().toString();
var hey = now + 'POST/api/v1/orders{"clientOid":"ADAUSDT","side":"buy","symbol":"ADA-USDT","price":"0.001","size":"50000"}';

/* signature */
var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(hey, api_secret);
signatureInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);

/* passphrase */
var passphrase = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(api_passphrase, api_secret);
passphraseInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(passphrase);

var headers = {
    "KC-API-SIGN": signatureInBase64,
    "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": now,
    "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
    "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphraseInBase64,
    "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2"
}

var url = burl + 'POST/api/v1/orders{"clientOid":"ADAUSDT","side":"buy","symbol":"ADA-USDT","price":"0.001","size":"50000"}';
$.ajax({
    headers: headers,
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I always receive the following error with my POST request:

> code: '400005', msg: 'Invalid KC-API-SIGN'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. First of all in the string you want to sign, you have to include method. Then you need to define a body. If there is no body you should pass body="". Then you have to parse Date.now() to string. For example:

```
var now = Date.now().toString();
var hey = now + method + url + body;
```

After writing this I saw that you included the method in url already, so that's fine too.

Side note: I didn't use CryptoJS. I used crypto module of node.js.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, sorry I didn't get back to you. Frustratingly I still can't get my POST requests working.  I have updated the code above with my latest. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: Other than your base URL, which I think it should be just Kucoin base URL, I have no idea what is the problem. A suggestion though: Use kucoin's node.js packages for these kind of stuff. There are two packages that I am familiar with: One is Kucoin API SDK for node and the other is kucoin-node-api. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me again. Unfortunately I can't use node.js as I'm trying to do these REST requests in the browser console. It's probably impossible because of CORS. Thanks for your time 

Comment: No Problem. In that case you might use an extension for your browser. There is an extension for CORS for browsers. But this is not practical. Good luck!

Comment: what does "method" mean in this context?

Comment: @Jim Here it is http request method. For example GET or POST depending on the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the step to solve this guys, if you are using NodeJs.

1. NPM Install crypto-js
2. Import it into the file you will be using and also axios then use the code snippet below.

   ```
   const axios = require("axios");
   const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

   class Authenticator {

   async signRequest(payload) {

       let { method, url, body, api_secret, api_passphrase, api_key } = payload

       try {

           const now = Date.now().toString();

           let queryStringPost = now + method + url + JSON.stringify(body);
           let queryStringGET = now + method + url;

           let queryString = method == "POST" ? queryStringPost : queryStringGET;

           console.log({queryString});

           /* signature */
           const signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(queryString, api_secret);
           const signatureInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);

           /* passphrase */
           const passphrase = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(api_passphrase, api_secret);
           const passphraseInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(passphrase);

           const fullUrl = `${process.env.KUCOIN_BASE_URL}${url}`

           console.log({fullUrl});

           if(method == "POST"){
               const responseFromKucoin = await axios.post(fullUrl, body, {
                   headers: {
                       "KC-API-SIGN": signatureInBase64,
                       "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": now,
                       "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
                       "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphraseInBase64,
                       "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2"
                   },
               })

               const resp = responseFromKucoin.data

               console.log({ resp });
           }else{
               const responseFromKucoin = await axios.get(fullUrl,{
                   headers: {
                       "KC-API-SIGN": signatureInBase64,
                       "KC-API-TIMESTAMP": now,
                       "KC-API-KEY": api_key,
                       "KC-API-PASSPHRASE": passphraseInBase64,
                       "KC-API-KEY-VERSION": "2"
                   },
               })

               const resp = responseFromKucoin.data

               console.log({ resp });

               return resp;
           }



       } catch (err) {
           console.log({err});
       }
   }

   }


   module.exports = Authenticator
   ```

A Sample request of the request I made to the class.

```
const create = await new Kucoin().signRequest({
            method:"POST",
            url:"/api/v1/orders",
            body:{"clientOid":"ETHUSDT", side:"buy", symbol:"ETH-USDT", type:"market", size:"2000"},
            api_secret:process.env.KUCOIN_API_SECRET,
            api_passphrase:process.env.KUCOIN_PASSPHRASE,
            api_key:process.env.KUCOIN_API_KEY,  
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you have missed out Content-Type:application/json in the header :)